# ImportExport API - Access is denied for the user NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE

Tags: a4t, importexportservice

> Blockquote

I'm working on an Alchemy plugin, and I'm having trouble using the importexport service to export a simple package. I'm getting an access denied error, which is baffling me because I don't see any NETWORK SERVICE user anywhere on the system, and also because my code attempts to explicitly set the user to something else.

```
try
{
    var selection = new Selection[] { new ItemsSelection(tcms) };

    var endpointIdentity = EndpointIdentity.CreateUpnIdentity("WIN-DFMAJQHT95L\\Administrator");

    var endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(new Uri("http://localhost:81/webservices/ImportExportService2013.svc/basicHttp"),
                                                  endpointIdentity, 
                                                  new AddressHeader[0]{});

    var binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
    binding.Name = "ImportExport_basicHttpBinding";
    binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly;
    binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Windows;

    var importExportClient = new ImportExportServiceClient(binding, endpointAddress);

    var exportInstruction = new ExportInstruction()
    {
        LogLevel = LogLevel.Normal,
        BluePrintMode = BluePrintMode.ExportSharedItemsFromOwningPublication,
        //ExpandDependenciesOfTypes = IncludeDependencyTypes
    };

    var processId = importExportClient.StartExport(selection, exportInstruction);
}
```

The error I'm getting is:

System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.Client.ImportExportServiceFault]: Access is denied for the user NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE. (Fault Detail is equal to Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.Client.ImportExportServiceFault).

Any suggestions?

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.Client.IImportExportService.StartExport(Selection[] selections, ExportInstruction instruction)
   at LatestItems.Controllers.LatestItemsServiceController.GetExportConfig(ExportConfigRequest request)

Comment: This message is what I would expect if the client credentials are not being sent (seems to be the case). At a guess, the line where you're getting the windows credentials is running server-side, and is getting the ID under which the process is running (NETWORK SERVICE) instead of the logged in user.

Comment: Which line are you referring to? When I  create my endpointIdentitty, I've tested explicitly setting the username to an Admin or current windows user - and in all cases, I've confirmed by writing out to a log that the user is NOT the NETWORK SERVICE user.

Comment: I suspect I have a similar issue and/or require a similar solution as this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12044338/tridion-coreservice-authentication-impersonation

Comment: Adding this code seems promising. However, I don't want to have to deal with any passwords:
-------------

var credentials = new NetworkCredential("Administrator", "<password>");
importExportClient.ChannelFactory.Credentials.Windows.ClientCredential = credentials;

Answer (score 1):

Adding this code seems to be the best solution:

```
var credentials = new NetworkCredential("Administrator", "<password>"); 
importExportClient.ChannelFactory.Credentials.Windows.ClientCredential = credentials;
```

Continuing with the export and then writing the code to download the package, there were a few other issues that I eventually managed to resolve by comparing my code to the Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.Common.dll.config file. Basically all pertinent information in that config file needed to be replicated in the C# code, because as an Alchemy plugin there is no .config file to merge that information into.

Comment: Agree that this is not optimal, you should be able to use the _current_ user. Keep on searching, there must be a way to get it correctly. At least, this confirms that the issue is you're not getting/passing the correct credentials.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. With the core service, this is normally done using client.Impersonate(), but with the importExportClient, there is no Impersonate() method, or anything similar, that I am aware of. I guess that makes sense, since Content Porter asks for credentials separately from the CME. However, this is a major blocker for my plugin and it means I have no nice way to interact securely with the importExport service from the client side in my plugin.